# How to call a function that's in MainPage.xaml.cs from App.xaml.cs

Tags: c#, xaml

I am building a language translator application. I am using an API to get all the languages that the user can translate their input into and storing them in a picker. Currently, I am trying to retrieve and load all the languages into the picker once the application starts. I have tried implementing the OnStartUp function in App.xaml.cs by doing the following:

**App.xaml.cs**

```
protected override void OnStart()
{
    var mainPage = new MainPage();
    this.MainPage = mainPage;

    mainPage.getLanguages();
}
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LanguageTranslator"
             x:Class="LanguageTranslator.MainPage">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />

                      .......

<StackLayout x:Name="slLanguages" Grid.Row="5" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="3, 6, 3, 3">
            <Label Text="Languages: " />
            <Picker x:Name="pckLanguages">
                <Picker.Items>

                </Picker.Items>
                <Picker.SelectedIndex>1</Picker.SelectedIndex>
            </Picker>
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
public void getLanguages()
{
        #region Load all available languages into the picker 'pckLangugages'
        // Fills the picker 'pckLanguages' with all available langauges when the main page is loaded
        var serverResponse = Request(string.Format(ApiSetup.getLanguages, ApiSetup.APIKey, lblSourceLanguage.Text));
        var dictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary>(serverResponse.Content); // Converts the server response into JSON format 

        foreach (DictionaryEntry dictionaryEntry in dictionary)
        {
            if (dictionaryEntry.Key.Equals("langs"))
            {
                var languages = (JObject)dictionaryEntry.Value;
                LanguagesList = new List<string>();

                pckLanguages.Items.Clear();

                foreach (var lang in languages)
                {
                    if (!lang.Equals(lblSourceLanguage.Text))
                    {
                        pckLanguages.Items.Add(lang.Value.ToString());
                        LanguagesList.Add(lang.Key);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

(`Request` is a function that sets up a RestSharp client and request. `ApiSetup` is a class that handles the API side of things - getting all available languages, detecting source language, etc.`pckLanguages` is a picker in MainPage.xaml that allows the user to choose a language to which they can translate their entered text into).

While OnStartUp does seem to get called (if I Debug.Write something, it will get printed to the console). I have also tried using OnAppearing but to no avail:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
       getLanguages();
}
```

I have also tried using a [loaded event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/how-to-handle-a-loaded-event) but the property 'Loaded' was not found on StackPanel.

If anyone has any ideas of a good way to solve this and/or knows what I'm doing wrong, it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't. This points to bad design. If you need to call this function from more than one page put it in a library that both use.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the easiest thing would be to create a static class. You would have a method in this class where you would store this data in a static field. It would be available everywhere where you use this class.